# Enqueue method in CircularArrayQueue class

Tags: java, queue, adt

I have come across the `enqueue()` method in `CircularArrayQueue` class:

```
public void enqueue (T element) {
if (size() == queue.length){
expandCapacity();
}
queue[rear] = element;
rear = (rear+1) % queue.length;
count++;
}
```

I don't quite understand what the `rear = (rear+1) % queue.length;` part of the code does, can someone break down the steps of that line of code.

I do understand that it increments `rear` as a new element has been added however I am unsure of the `%` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to visualize what is happening is to imagine a clock (often used as an analogy for modular arithmetic, which is happening in the line you mentioned with the use of the % operator).

For example, imagine that the `CircularArrayQueue` has a size of 4 at the moment and that its length is 5 (indices 0 - 4). In the example below, the current value of rear is 4 (index 4)

The items in the internal array might look like this:

```
INDEX | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
VALUE |   | 8 | 9 | 2 | 1 |
                        ^
                        |
                       Rear
```

Now let's say that you insert the value 7 into the `CircularArrayQueue`, then the line

```
rear = (rear + 1) % queue.length;
```

would be executed. This effectively computes the following:

```
add 1 to rear (4) -> 5
divide by queue.length (5) -> 5 / 5 = 1 (remainder of 0)
take the remainder of the previous division (0) and set it equal to rear

INDEX | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
VALUE | 7 | 8 | 9 | 2 | 1 |
        ^
        |
       Rear
```

so after all of these steps, rear now equals 0 and points to the first index in the internal array of the `CircularArrayQueue`. This behavior of the index "wrapping back around" the array when it reaches the end is the circular behavior that is characteristic of a `CircularArrayQueue`.

The way that this relates to a clock, is that the minute hand on a clock always "wraps back around" when it reaches 60, and "resets" back to 0.

In other words, the internal array used as an example above, can be thought of as a clock with only 5 minutes (indices 0 - 4). You can think of (rear + 1) as advancing by a minute on the clock. After the "minute hand" (rear) has been incremented 4 times, it starts again at 0.

Comment: How can the `CircularArrayQueue` have a size of `4` and a length of `5`, that is a bit confusing?

Comment: The internal array has a length of 5, meaning its physical size is 5 elements, but it has a logical size of 4 - only 4 of the 5 available spaces are occupied by elements.

Answer (score 0):

`rear = (rear+1) % queue.length;` achieves circularity. As `CircularArrayQueue` class name suggests it is circular. It means that when the last element (`queue.length`-th) is reached it begins to insert elements from the beginning. `rear = (rear+1) % queue.length` returns `rear+1` in case the `rear+1 < queue.length` , and 0 if `rear+1 == queue.length` and in this case it start inserting elements from the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 0):

it basically rounding your queue index for circular queue.

> lets say your array queue.length==10,so when rear incremented to 10 it will be rounded to 0 to insert next element at 0 index.